# 500 (Internal Server Error) with React Express and CORS

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, cors

https://github.com/joshua-sigston/MERN-book-app.

Running into a 500 internal server error and cant figure out why. The data is going to the backend but not the database. Data does not get submitted. I am trying to submit new data to a mongodb database

Tried reconfiguring cors but nothing seems to work

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).